# Replicating messages from one Kafka topic to another kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka

I want to make a flow from a Kafka cluster/topic in thr prod cluster into another Kafka cluster in the dev environment for scalability and regrrssion testing.

For the duck-tape solution, I cascade a Kafka consumer and producer, but my instinct tells me that there should be a better way. But, I couldn't find any good solution yet. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you want to replicate data from one cluster to another then there is one kafka tool called `MirrorMaker`.

> Kafka comes with a tool for mirroring data between Kafka clusters. The tool reads from a source cluster and writes to a destination cluster. Data will be read from topics in the source cluster and written to a topic with the same name in the destination cluster.

Here is syntax to run `MirrorMaker` tool:

```
bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.MirrorMaker
       --consumer.config consumer.properties
       --producer.config producer.properties --whitelist my-topic
```

You can find this script in kafka installation directory. Here you need to provide `consumer.properties` of your `source cluster` and `producer.properties` of your `destination cluster`. You can whitelist which topics should be mirrored through `--whitelist` option.

You can find more information about [Mirroring data between clusters](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#basic_ops_mirror_maker)

**Note:** MirrorMaker copies data into same `topic_name` in `destination cluster` as `source cluster`

Comment: Great tool! But what if I need only last N messages from topic T? In our case prod topic is too huge, and we need only part of it each day (say last 1M messages) to use in uat env.

Comment: What happens to the offsets in the original topic and new topic?

Comment: in my case, im looking to take a partial window of data from the original topic to the new topic.

Answer (score 11):

While mirror makes works perfect for across the cluster solution, however, for same cluster your ducktap solution is not bad as MirrorMaker assumes you are pulling from one cluster to another cluster.

So a solution where you simply want to copy data between different topics in the same cluster, kafkacat is your friend.

```
export BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=localhost:9096
export SOURCE_TOPIC=source_topic
export TARGET_TOPIC=target_topic

kafkacat -C -b $BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS -o beginning -e -t $SOURCE_TOPIC  | kafkacat -P -b $BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS  -t $TARGET_TOPIC
```

Comment: For those wondering, kafkacat is a tool from Magnus Edenhill and can be found on GitHub at https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat

Comment: When I tried this, it copied the topic but not the messages.

Comment: The keys aren't reflected in the new topic. Additionally, multi-line messages seem to be reduced to one arbitrary line, so that's inconsistent copying. :(

Comment: this copies only the message values: it will not preserve headers and keys

Comment: @ChrisBlom what abt original timestamps ?

Comment: timestamps are also not preserved with this method

Answer (score 0):

Kafka is basically a messaging queue, therefore it has a passive behavior: something has to put messages **into** it (`producer`), and something has to pull messages **from** it (`consumer`).

If you want to make a sort of pipeline between two kafka topics, so that messages from one topic will go automatically to the other topic, you'll need some code which will have the properties of consumer from the first topic and a producer to the second topic.

Depending on your programming language, you can choose between some ready-to-go well documented producer and/or consumer solutions.

For more sophisticated cases you can check out *Apache Storm*, etc.

Comment: You can also use a different consumer-group.
Example: Consumer1 uses groupId 'first-group-name' 
Consumer2 uses groupId 'second-group-name', for the same messages to be read by two of these consumers without the need of adding a new topic. Simply modify the listener of your topic to accomodate this.

Answer (score 0):

And if you need to copy messages from one topic into another topic, maybe with some additional logic or transformation, you can also use **Kafka Streams**.

https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/index.html

And examples

https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/5.4.0-post/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/WordCountLambdaExample.java

Alternatively, check `MirrorMaker`.

Comment: In terms of Kafka streams way, do you mean we use multiple @Bean Java.until.Consumer listening to that topic? Or are there any other ways using Kafka Stream? FYI I am using Spring Cloud Stream 3.0. Thanks

Comment: Kafka Streams only works in the same cluster.